# Cant connect to my HTTP sever outside of my local network

Tags: web-hosting

I have recently hosted a website on my ubuntu pc and I can access the page at `localhost` and my external ip. but when I try typing my external IP on my phone that is connected to is own network (3g) not wifi I get `Google chromes connection attempt was rejected` I have set up port forwarding on port 80. what have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your ISP?   Many service providers don't allow inbound traffic on port 80 to prevent residential customers from running web servers.

Internode's [help page](http://www.internode.on.net/support/security/network_firewall/) says that there is a firewall that blocks port 80.   It has instructions for disabling it.

Comment: http://www.internode.on.net/